# installing d3ML in React without npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, d3.js

I came across `d3ML.js`. However, it's not in the npm registry so I can't directly install it. Is there any other to install & use it in a React.js project?

Comment: Do you mean [this github page](https://github.com/StefanieStoppel/d3ML/tree/master)?

Comment: Yes. As mentioned on this page, it's not on npm. If using plain html/js, we can add the script but how can we do so in react and react native? @RubenHelsloot

Comment: Just download the source files and add them to your project. Then import them from there as if they were your own code. They should be included into your bundle by Webpack/Rollup/your build manager